# Value of type '1-dimensional array of String' cannot be converted to 'String'. (BC30311)

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0

I have this code which gives an error:

```
'declaration
Dim strFieldValues As String
'split
strFieldValues = strRecord.Split(",") 'field are separated by commas
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, the error seems to be pretty self-explanatory to me. You've declared a variable of type `String` - i.e. it can hold a value of a *single `String` reference*:

```
Dim strFieldValues As String
```

You've then tried to assign a value to it returned from `String.Split()`:

```
strFieldValues = strRecord.Split(",")
```

Now [`String.Split()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) returns a `String` *array*, not a single string value.

So you have two courses of action open to you:

- Change `strFieldValues` to an array variable
- Change the value you assign to it

My guess is that you want the first, but we don't know what you're trying to achieve. The simplest approach would be to combine declaration and initialization:

```
Dim strFieldValues = strRecord.Split(",")
```

You may also need to change the arguments to `Split` - I don't know how VB will sort out that call.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is just retrieve either side of the resulting string array, you could just invoke the left or right part like this:

```
strFieldValues = strRecord.Split(",")(0) ' Text to the left of the delimiter character
```

Or

```
strFieldValues = strRecord.Split(",")(1) ' Text to the right of the delimiter character
```

Of course, this assumes that the delimiter character does exist, so you should take the necessary precautions to ensure that you won't run into a runtime exception if said character is not found on the string you are splitting.